# Count number of occurences of [x] amount of zeros only after the occurence of first 1 in a row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table which has only 0s and 1s in ~50 columns and ~13k rows.
What I want to do is to calculate how many times did a series of specific amount of zeroes occured in each row, after the first 1 has occured.

Example: in a given row, in column number 5 there is an occurrence of first 1 in a row. I want excel to count from column 5 until the end of the row (column 50 in that cas), the number of times that x amount of zeros has occured next to each other in neighbouring columns. The end effect is a table in which I can see that:

- number of series where exactly 1 zero occurred next to each other
- number of series where exactly 2 zeros occurred next to each other
- number of series where exactly n zeros occurred next to each other

Then I need to know in cases above, in how many of these occurrences:

- 1 occured again at some poin in a row
- 1 did not appear untill the end of the row (untill the 50th column)
  I guess these 2 events are mutually exclusive so if I have number of occurrences of a given series I can count both while having only 1.
  Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "exactly 2 zeros occurred next to each other" isn't that just 4 zeroes? Maybe provide sample data and expected outcome? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: In addition, specify: if there is not a single 1 in the row, is it [50]? If two 1s follow in a row, is it a [0]? If there are fifty 1 in the row, is it 49 of [0]?

Comment: I am almost certain this question has been answered. Try searching for "excel find all matches". Beyond that I suggest you look at getting the free excel web version which have new functions (sequence, let, lambda) that will make what I think you are trying to do much simpler. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the description of your task, from the whole row you are only interested in the length of the first series of consecutive 0 after the first 1 - not all available series, but only the first.

*You have tagged your question with #microsoft-excel-2007. This complicates the solution somewhat. As @gns100 pointed out in his comment, modern versions provide more flexible tools than the 15 year old program. However, even the simplest means can solve the problem.*

First of all, we list three possible cases that we can meet in the rows of a large table:

1. There is not a single 1 in the line - that means there is not a
   single series. In other words, the length of the run of zeros in
   this string is 0 (or -1?).
2. There is only one 1 in the entire row - it means that after it until
   the end of the row there is a solid strip of 0. The length of this
   strip is equal to the length of the entire row minus position of 1.
3. There is more than one 1 in the row - the length of this first
   series will be equal to the position of the second 1 minus the
   position of the first 1 minus 1. For example, for the row
   **{0,0,1,0,0,1,0...}** the position of the second 1 is 6, the position of the first 1 is 3, the length of the series of zeros
   between them is `6-3-1=2`. If two 1's are adjacent, then the length
   of sequence is 0.

To understand which of the options we met in the next row, we simply count the number of 1s in this row. The [**COUNTIF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) will give us the desired number.

Now we use the [**SIGN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sign-function-109c932d-fcdc-4023-91f1-2dd0e916a1d8) to reduce all possible options to the three described. A construction similar to `SIGN(COUNTIF(A1:AX1;1)-1)+2` will return us 1,2 or 3 - the numbers of options from our list.

Now we use the [**CHOOSE()**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc) function to process each of the choices.

The first option is the simplest - it's just **0**.

For the second option, to find the position 1 in the row, use the [**MATCH() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

We could just write `50-MATCH(1;A1:AX1;0)`. But you used `~50` in the description of the problem, that is, the length of the row may be different. Therefore, instead of the constant 50, we use the [**COUNT() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-function-a59cd7fc-b623-4d93-87a4-d23bf411294c)

`COUNT(A1:AX1)-MATCH(1;A1:AX1;0)`

*(For my example, I use the **AX** column as the right border of the range to be processed - you may need to change it to another)*

To find the positions of the second and first 1, we use the following trick: replace all 1s with their [**column numbers**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/column-function-44e8c754-711c-4df3-9da4-47a55042554b), and replace all 0s with an empty string - `IF(A1:AX1=1;COLUMN(A1:AX1);"")`. So the row **{0,0,1,0,0,1,0...}** becomes **{,,3,,,6,,...}**.

Now, using the [**SMALL() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/small-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07), it is easy to get the desired values:

`SMALL(IF(A1:AX1=1;COLUMN(A1:AX1);"");2)-SMALL(IF(A1:AX1=1;COLUMN(A1:AX1);"");1)-1`

Let's collect all the parts in one formula. Write in **BE1**

```
=CHOOSE(SIGN(COUNTIF(A1:AX1;1)-1)+2;0;COUNT(A1:AX1)-MATCH(1;A1:AX1;0);SMALL(IF(A1:AX1=1;COLUMN(A1:AX1);"");2)-SMALL(IF(A1:AX1=1;COLUMN(A1:AX1);"");1)-1)
```

and complete your input by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Copy this cell to the end of the data - now in column BE you have the lengths of each of the first series 0 for each row

To count how many times each length occurs, you can use a [**Pivot Table**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576). Or you can do otherwise - use the [**FREQUENCY() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/frequency-function-44e3be2b-eca0-42cd-a3f7-fd9ea898fdb9):

- write in cells **BH1:BI1** the headings of the future table, for
  example, **[X]** and **Count [X]**
- fill cells **BH2:BH52** with values from **0** to **50** (for example,    write formula `=ROW()-2` in **BH2** and drag it down)
- select the range **BI2:BI52**, write the formula `=FREQUENCY(BE1:BE13000;BH2:BH51)`  and press
  **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Now that you know the sequence of actions for the calculation, it will not be difficult to state this in the form of a user-defined function in VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Function SeriesFrequency(rSource As Range) As Variant
Dim aResult As Variant
Dim rRow As Range
Dim nLenRow As Long, i As Long
Dim iLenSeries As Integer
Dim FirstPos As Long
    nLenRow = rSource.Columns.Count
    ReDim aResult(0 To nLenRow, 0 To 1)
    For i = 0 To nLenRow
        aResult(i, 0) = i
        aResult(i, 1) = 0
    Next i
    For Each rRow In rSource.Rows
        Select Case Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRow, 1)
        Case 0
            aResult(0, 1) = aResult(0, 1) + 1
        Case 1
            iLenSeries = nLenRow - Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, rRow, 0)
            aResult(iLenSeries, 1) = aResult(iLenSeries, 1) + 1
        Case Else
            FirstPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, rRow, 0)
            iLenSeries = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, rRow.Offset(0, FirstPos), 0) - 1
            aResult(iLenSeries, 1) = aResult(iLenSeries, 1) + 1
        End Select
    Next rRow
    SeriesFrequency = aResult
End Function
```

Just select the range you want, for example BH2:BI52, type something like `=SeriesFrequency(A1:AX13000)` and hit **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**

Now that you know how to use `COUNTIF(<range>,1)` values, you can easily solve the second part of the task: if there is more than one unit in the range, then the series 0 ends before reaching the end of the row.